# How to stop further input python tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, lambda

So I am making a calculator with tkinter in python and i have created everything perfectly fine, however after the program displays a result from a users input (example 5+5 = 10) how do I stop the user from being able to change the displayed answer in the entry bar (for example, if they enter 5 + 5 = 10 then if they click 6 the display shows 106) how do is stop this

```
    # import tkinter
from tkinter import *
# create tk systems and create title of program
root = Tk()
root.title("Calc")
subvar = 0
ticket = 0
# create entry bar
# Call this e for easy recall
# Define properties of entry bar
e = Entry(root, borderwidth=5, width=35)
# position entry bar using columns grids and padding
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=5, padx=10)

# Create a function for when user presses number to add on entry
def button_add(number):
    # Create new vairble for current entered number
    current = e.get() # Use .get to pull number value from button
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)
    # Put number on screen in entry widget and store as string
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

# Function to clear value in entry widget
def button_clear():
    e.delete(0, END)

# + Function -  Function to add to numbers together when "+" is pressed
def function_add():

    global subvar
    subvar = 0

    # Create Variable for first user input number
    input1 = e.get()
    # define as global variable to use out of function_add
    global num1
    # Assign global variable an integer value which is the users inputted number
    num1 = int(input1)
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)

# Subtract Function -  Function to add to numbers together when "-" is pressed
def function_subtract():

    global subvar

    subvar = 1

    # Create Variable for first user input number
    input1 = e.get()
    # define as global variable
    global num1
    # Assign global variable an integer value which is the users inputted number
    num1 = int(input1)
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)

def function_multiply():

    global subvar

    subvar = 3

    # Create Variable for first user input number
    input1 = e.get()
    # define as global variable
    global num1
    # Assign global variable an integer value which is the users inputted number
    num1 = int(input1)
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)


def function_divide():

    global subvar

    subvar = 4

    # Create Variable for first user input number
    input1 = e.get()
    # define as global variable
    global num1
    # Assign global variable an integer value which is the users inputted number
    num1 = int(input1)
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)


#  = Function - Create function to perform funcition  and display 2 added numbers,

def function_equal():

    global ticket

    if subvar == 1:

        input2 = e.get()
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, num1 - int(input2))
        ticket = 1
    elif subvar == 0:

        input2 = e.get()
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, num1 + int(input2))
        ticket = 1
    elif subvar == 3:

        input2 = e.get()
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, num1 * int(input2))
        ticket = 1
    elif subvar == 4:

        input2 = e.get()
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, num1 / int(input2))
        ticket = 1
# Create variables for each number value 0-9, define it as button widget, assign its physcal aspects

# create a command function and use Lambda to readily & repeatedly call button add with a select value


button1 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(1), text="1", padx=35, pady=10, )
button2 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(2), text="2", padx=35, pady=10, )
button3 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(3), text="3", padx=35, pady=10, )

button4 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(4), text="4", padx=35, pady=10, )
button5 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(5), text="5", padx=35, pady=10, )
button6 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(6),  text="6", padx=35, pady=10, )

button7 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(7), text="7", padx=35, pady=10, )
button8 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(8), text="8", padx=35, pady=10, )
button9 = Button(root,  command=lambda: button_add(9), text="9", padx=35, pady=10, )

button0 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(0), text="0", padx=35, pady=15, )
# Create variable for clear,add,equals and assign it as button widget, use command to call  function when pressed
buttonAdd = Button(root, text="+", padx=40, pady=20, command=function_add)
buttonSub = Button(root, text="-", padx=40, pady=20, command=function_subtract)
buttonMult = Button(root, text="x", padx=40, pady=20, command=function_multiply)
buttonDiv = Button(root, text="/", padx=40, pady=20, command=function_divide)
buttonClear = Button(root, text="Clr", padx=50, pady=20, command=button_clear)
buttonEqual = Button(root, text="=", padx=55, pady=20, command=function_equal)


# grid system to position numbers 1-3

button1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button3.grid(row=1, column=2)
# grid system to position numbers 1-3
button4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button6.grid(row=2, column=2)
# grid system to position numbers 1-3
button7.grid(row=3, column=0)
button8.grid(row=3, column=1)
button9.grid(row=3, column=2)
button0.grid(row=4, column=0)
# grid system to position all functions

buttonAdd.grid(row=5, column=0)
buttonSub.grid(row=5, column=1)
buttonMult.grid(row=5, column=2)
buttonDiv.grid(row=5, column=3)
buttonEqual.grid(row=4, column=2, )
buttonClear.grid(row=4, column=1, )


# This constantly loops the system and accounts for user movement and input, instead of having an uninteractable static system
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a variable *user_entry* ..
It gets set to False when the user presses "=" and gets set to True when the user presses "Clr" .. When *user_entry* = *False*, the *button_add* function returns and doesn't allow numbers to be entered into the field.

```
# import tkinter
from tkinter import *
# create tk systems and create title of program
root = Tk()
root.title("Calc")
subvar = 0
ticket = 0
user_entry = True
# create entry bar
# Call this e for easy recall
# Define properties of entry bar
e = Entry(root, borderwidth=5, width=35)
# position entry bar using columns grids and padding
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, pady=5, padx=10)

# Create a function for when user presses number to add on entry
def button_add(number):
    if not user_entry: return
    # Create new vairble for current entered number
    current = e.get() # Use .get to pull number value from button
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)
    # Put number on screen in entry widget and store as string
    e.insert(0, str(current) + str(number))

# Function to clear value in entry widget
def button_clear():
    global user_entry
    user_entry = True
    e.delete(0, END)

# + Function -  Function to add to numbers together when "+" is pressed
def function_add():

    global subvar
    subvar = 0

    # Create Variable for first user input number
    input1 = e.get()
    # define as global variable to use out of function_add
    global num1
    # Assign global variable an integer value which is the users inputted number
    num1 = int(input1)
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)

# Subtract Function -  Function to add to numbers together when "-" is pressed
def function_subtract():
    global subvar

    subvar = 1

    # Create Variable for first user input number
    input1 = e.get()
    # define as global variable
    global num1
    # Assign global variable an integer value which is the users inputted number
    num1 = int(input1)
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)

def function_multiply():

    global subvar

    subvar = 3

    # Create Variable for first user input number
    input1 = e.get()
    # define as global variable
    global num1
    # Assign global variable an integer value which is the users inputted number
    num1 = int(input1)
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)


def function_divide():

    global subvar

    subvar = 4

    # Create Variable for first user input number
    input1 = e.get()
    # define as global variable
    global num1
    # Assign global variable an integer value which is the users inputted number
    num1 = int(input1)
    # Return
    e.delete(0, END)


#  = Function - Create function to perform funcition  and display 2 added numbers,

def function_equal():
    global user_entry
    user_entry = False

    global ticket

    if subvar == 1:

        input2 = e.get()
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, num1 - int(input2))
        ticket = 1
    elif subvar == 0:

        input2 = e.get()
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, num1 + int(input2))
        ticket = 1
    elif subvar == 3:

        input2 = e.get()
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, num1 * int(input2))
        ticket = 1
    elif subvar == 4:

        input2 = e.get()
        e.delete(0, END)
        e.insert(0, num1 / int(input2))
        ticket = 1
    
# Create variables for each number value 0-9, define it as button widget, assign its physcal aspects

# create a command function and use Lambda to readily & repeatedly call button add with a select value


button1 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(1), text="1", padx=35, pady=10, )
button2 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(2), text="2", padx=35, pady=10, )
button3 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(3), text="3", padx=35, pady=10, )

button4 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(4), text="4", padx=35, pady=10, )
button5 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(5), text="5", padx=35, pady=10, )
button6 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(6),  text="6", padx=35, pady=10, )

button7 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(7), text="7", padx=35, pady=10, )
button8 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(8), text="8", padx=35, pady=10, )
button9 = Button(root,  command=lambda: button_add(9), text="9", padx=35, pady=10, )

button0 = Button(root, command=lambda: button_add(0), text="0", padx=35, pady=15, )
# Create variable for clear,add,equals and assign it as button widget, use command to call  function when pressed
buttonAdd = Button(root, text="+", padx=40, pady=20, command=function_add)
buttonSub = Button(root, text="-", padx=40, pady=20, command=function_subtract)
buttonMult = Button(root, text="x", padx=40, pady=20, command=function_multiply)
buttonDiv = Button(root, text="/", padx=40, pady=20, command=function_divide)
buttonClear = Button(root, text="Clr", padx=50, pady=20, command=button_clear)
buttonEqual = Button(root, text="=", padx=55, pady=20, command=function_equal)


# grid system to position numbers 1-3

button1.grid(row=1, column=0)
button2.grid(row=1, column=1)
button3.grid(row=1, column=2)
# grid system to position numbers 1-3
button4.grid(row=2, column=0)
button5.grid(row=2, column=1)
button6.grid(row=2, column=2)
# grid system to position numbers 1-3
button7.grid(row=3, column=0)
button8.grid(row=3, column=1)
button9.grid(row=3, column=2)
button0.grid(row=4, column=0)
# grid system to position all functions

buttonAdd.grid(row=5, column=0)
buttonSub.grid(row=5, column=1)
buttonMult.grid(row=5, column=2)
buttonDiv.grid(row=5, column=3)
buttonEqual.grid(row=4, column=2, )
buttonClear.grid(row=4, column=1, )


# This constantly loops the system and accounts for user movement and input, instead of having an uninteractable static system
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: works great although I have a question, now what if the user want to use the addition function or subtraction function after they have clicked enter (for example, user does 5 - 5, gets answer 0 then wants to add another 5, how would you go about disabling and reenlabling the number addition if a function is called again?